# Unity crash when I am trying to slowly make a particle system disappear (C code)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I made something and for some reason unity just crashed after this code is being executed.
What I want to do is to slowly make particle system disappear.
This is the code:

```
public float TimeToDestroy;
private ParticleSystem ParticleSystem;
private float MaxParticle;
private float OriginalTimeToDestroy;
private float OriginalMaxParticle;
private void Start()
{
    ParticleSystem = GetComponent<ParticleSystem>();
    OriginalTimeToDestroy = TimeToDestroy;
    MaxParticle = ParticleSystem.maxParticles;
    OriginalMaxParticle = MaxParticle;
    Destroy(gameObject, TimeToDestroy);
    while (TimeToDestroy >= 0)
    {
        MaxParticle = Mathf.Lerp(OriginalMaxParticle, 0, OriginalTimeToDestroy);
        ParticleSystem.maxParticles = Mathf.RoundToInt(MaxParticle);
    }
    Destroy(gameObject);
}
private void Update()
{
    TimeToDestroy -= Time.deltaTime;
}
```

Comment: while (TimeToDestroy >= 0)    is an infinite loop, so you won't be able to get out. Shouldn't this while be in the Update method ?

Answer (score 0):

Malphegal said it all, you have an infinite loop. You never give bak the control to Unity so that the `Update` can run (and `TimeToDestroy` decreases), so it freezes. Either use the Update method as advised by Malphegal, or make `Start` a coroutine.

### Coroutine way

```cs
public float TimeToDestroy;
private ParticleSystem ParticleSystem;
private float MaxParticle;
private float OriginalTimeToDestroy;
private float OriginalMaxParticle;

private IEnumerator Start()
{
    ParticleSystem = GetComponent<ParticleSystem>();
    OriginalTimeToDestroy = TimeToDestroy;
    MaxParticle = ParticleSystem.maxParticles;
    OriginalMaxParticle = MaxParticle;
    while (TimeToDestroy >= 0)
    {
        MaxParticle = Mathf.Lerp(OriginalMaxParticle, 0, OriginalTimeToDestroy);
        ParticleSystem.maxParticles = Mathf.RoundToInt(MaxParticle);
        yield return null;
        TimeToDestroy -= Time.deltaTime;
    }
    Destroy(gameObject);
}
```

### `Update` way

```cs
public float TimeToDestroy;
private ParticleSystem ParticleSystem;
private float MaxParticle;
private float OriginalTimeToDestroy;
private float OriginalMaxParticle;

private void Start()
{
    ParticleSystem = GetComponent<ParticleSystem>();
    OriginalTimeToDestroy = TimeToDestroy;
    MaxParticle = ParticleSystem.maxParticles;
    OriginalMaxParticle = MaxParticle;
}

private void Update()
{
    if(TimeToDestroy >= 0)
    {
        TimeToDestroy -= Time.deltaTime;
        MaxParticle = Mathf.Lerp(OriginalMaxParticle, 0, OriginalTimeToDestroy);
        ParticleSystem.maxParticles = Mathf.RoundToInt(MaxParticle);
    }
    else
        Destroy(gameObject);
}
```